# How to Navigate JSONP from Goodreads?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, jsonp

I'm attempting to get data from Goodreads' API to display the rating for a book, but I'm running into a roadblock.

From this URL (`https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json?isbns=9781630586799&key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myCallback`), I'm recieving the below JSONP data from Goodreads:

```
myCallback([{
    "id":22571333,
    "isbn":"163058679X",
    "isbn13":"9781630586799",
    "ratings_count":657,
    "reviews_count":2288,
    "text_reviews_count":138,
    "work_ratings_count":835,
    "work_reviews_count":2596,
    "work_text_reviews_count":155,
    "average_rating":"3.93"
}])
```

And here's my javascript:

```
function myCallback(result) {
    document.getElementById('goodreads-rating').innerHTML = result.average_rating;
}

var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.src = "https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json?isbns=9781630586799&key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myCallback";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
```

The data I want to retrieve is the `average_rating`. However, what gets outputted to the HTML is the word "undefined".

I'm guessing my problem has something to do with how I'm navigating the array/object.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try `result[0].average_rating;` doh...

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved my problem:

```
result[0].average_rating;
```

I now realize I was trying to navigate within an array, hence the need to reference the index number `[0]`. Thanks to @dandavis for the answer!